# Keyword filed type for expression engine

Tags: expressionengine, pyrocms, fieldtype

Is there a solution for implementing the Field type "Keywords" in Expression Engine as it is in Pyro CMS ?

My problem is that I want to add keywords to my Channel "News" , & I want to be able to filter with them as I do with Categories , Archives, & Paginate them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a commercial plugin but could a plugin such as http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tagger be of use to you? That gives you keywords/tagging functionality as well as a means to filter/sort them.

Comment: Thanks @JamesNZ, I have used tagger already for this. It still has this one problem for me where I want to search with category & tag both at the same time. But that's okay. It worked for me.